# Integration AD B2C x QlikSense for Windows using OIDC

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, qliksense

Is there any article showing how to integrate Qlik Sense for Windows with Azure AD B2C? I'm trying to do an authentication using OIDC but I'm receiving:

**400 Contact your system administrator. The user cannot be authenticated or logged out by the OIDC response through the following virtual proxy: azure.**.

QlikSense virtual proxy configuration:
[image]

Azure User Flows:
[image]

Reply url:
https://[domain]/oidc_adb2c_uat/oidcauthn

Comment: Can you check browser devtools, can you see errors in network tab coming from AAD B2C?

Comment: I used to see but it only shows Bad Request. I know it's arriving at the QlikSense because it shows the name of the virtual proxy I configured.

Comment: Usually if something goes wrong at Azure AD B2C, it will return an error message in the response to the client, QlikSense in your case.

Comment: I think that the problem is on QlikSense configuration but I don't know which parameter is wrong: picture, sub, groups, scope, etc. Which one? I couldn't find an example.

Answer (score 0):

For the `email` property, trying using **email** instead of **emails** with an "s".

Comment: The same error :(. Have you ever did this integration AD B2C x QlikSense?